# Response.WriteFile index.html in Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My ASP.NET is not working as intended. I have set `mynow.Text` to a value of datatime, but I get this error:

> BC30451: name 'mynow' not declared message.

How can I solve this problem?

My page1.aspx:

```
Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" Debug="true"

<script runat="server">

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.WriteFile("index.html")        
End Sub    

Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    mynow.Text = DateTime.Now
End Sub

</script>
```

My index.html is only one simple line:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="mynow"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net doesn't work like that.
You need to put server-side controls inside the ASPX file.